# Error al instalar ipa en ipad entitlements no cuadran Xamarin

Tags: xamarin.ios

Tengo un problema al querer instalar un ipa en el iPad manda el error:
The entitlements specified in your application’s Code Signing Entitlements file are invalid, not permitted, or do not match those specified in your provisioning profile.
Buscando información indica que no cuadra el entitlements lo que esta en el portal de developer con lo que esta en la aplicación y es correcto en el portal vienen marcados por defecto la opción de Game Center y In App Purchase los cuales no se encuentran en el archivo Entiliments de Xamarin.
No puedo ver como meterlos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: configuracion develop]
[image: configuracion xamarin]

Answer (score 0):

En mi caso Game Center se encuentra en Info.plist no en Entitlements.plist, no se había habilitado, una vez habilitado ya no existe el problema.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]